# Test that function is executed in ES6 constructor using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, ecmascript-6

I have created [a simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/f18htp8L/1/) on JSFiddle to test a problem I encountered in my project:

```
describe('testing es6 and jasmine', function() {
  describe('let', () => {
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let
    it('is es6 works', function() {
      class Test {
        constructor() {
          var x = this.sum(1, 1);
        }
        sum(a, b) {
          return a + b;
        }
      }
      var test = new Test();
      spyOn(test, 'sum').and.callThrough();
      expect(test.sum).toBeDefined();
      expect(test.constructor).toBeDefined();
      expect(test.sum).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

  });
});
```

Problem is that I execute a method in the constructor and I want to check if it was executed. Why in my example does Jasmine tell that it is not ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you call the constructor (by using `new Test`) before you install the spy. So the function has already been called by the time it gets spied on.

To solve this, you can spy on `Test.prototype.sum`, *before* calling the constructor:

```
spyOn(Test.prototype, 'sum').and.callThrough();
var test = new Test();
```

See the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f18htp8L/2/).